# How to unit test reactjs component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to get my head around a unit testing a 'container' component. It looks something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IAppState {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  command: string;
  facing: string;
  init: boolean;
}

export class App extends Component<any, IAppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      command: '',
      facing: 'EAST',
      init: false
    };
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    const { x, y } = this.state;
    return (
      <div onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
        x:{x},y:{y}
      </div>
    );
  }

  private handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
    console.log('handlekeydown');

    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        console.log('key left');
        this.setState({ x: this.state.x - 1 });
        break;
      case 38:
        console.log('key up');
        this.setState({ y: this.state.y + 1 });
        break;
      case 39:
        console.log('key right');
        this.setState({ x: this.state.x + 1 });
        break;
      case 40:
        console.log('key down');
        this.setState({ y: this.state.y - 1 });
        break;
    }
  };
}
```

I know how to test 'presentational' components with mocking props but how can I test 'container' components?

This is my unit test, how can I test the function `handleKeyDown`?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createRenderer } from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import App from '../App';

it('does it render', () => {

    const props = {
      addTodo: jest.fn()
    }

    const renderer = createRenderer();
    renderer.render(< App />)
    const output = renderer.getRenderOutput()

    //todo expect component top level type
    console.log(output)

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-test-renderer` and snapshot testing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IAppState {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  command: string;
  facing: string;
  init: boolean;
}

export class App extends Component<any, IAppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      command: '',
      facing: 'EAST',
      init: false
    };
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    const { x, y } = this.state;
    return (
      <div onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
        x:{x},y:{y}
      </div>
    );
  }

  private handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
    console.log('handlekeydown');

    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        console.log('key left');
        this.setState({ x: this.state.x - 1 });
        break;
      case 38:
        console.log('key up');
        this.setState({ y: this.state.y + 1 });
        break;
      case 39:
        console.log('key right');
        this.setState({ x: this.state.x + 1 });
        break;
      case 40:
        console.log('key down');
        this.setState({ y: this.state.y - 1 });
        break;
    }
  };
}
```

snapshot testing:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { App } from './';

describe('App', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(<App></App>);
    let tree = testRenderer.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    if (tree) {
      tree.props.onKeyDown({ keyCode: 37 });
    }
    tree = testRenderer.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    if (tree) {
      tree.props.onKeyDown({ keyCode: 38 });
    }
    tree = testRenderer.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    if (tree) {
      tree.props.onKeyDown({ keyCode: 39 });
    }
    tree = testRenderer.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

    if (tree) {
      tree.props.onKeyDown({ keyCode: 40 });
    }
    tree = testRenderer.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Snapshot testing result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.spec.tsx
  App
    ✓ t1 (52ms)

 › 3 snapshots written.
  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1501
    handlekeydown

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1511
    key left

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1501
    handlekeydown

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1528
    key up

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1501
    handlekeydown

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1545
    key right

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1501
    handlekeydown

  console.log src/stackoverflow/46783353/index.tsx:1562
    key down

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Snapshot Summary
 › 3 snapshots written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   3 written, 2 passed, 5 total
Time:        5.897s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/46783353